# When is a level set an immersed submanifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, smooth-structures

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $f\in C^\infty(M)$. Let $S:=f^{-1}(\{c\})$ for some $c\in \operatorname{Im}(f)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. When does exist a manifold $N$ with $\dim(N)<\dim(M)$ and a smooth immersion $\Phi :N\rightarrow M$ such that $\Phi (N)=S$? I guess that the interior of $S$ has to be empty.

Furthermore: when is $N$ unique up to dipheomorphism?

It's a well known result that if $c$ is a regular value then $S$ is a closed embedded hypersurface, so, in that line of thinking, probably you need to put some conditions to $c$, but I don't know which ones.

Partial answers are also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I might take an issue with your question.  When you say you are asking for the "next level" of generality, what do you mean?  Can you describe all the levels of generality in some system?  I think usually people would take your line of questioning in a different direction, i.e. have a disagreement on the form of generalization.

Comment: @RyanBudney true. I'll delete it.

Comment: I am fairly certain this will be true if every critical point for $c$ is Morse (i.e. for every $x$ such that $f-c$ vanishes at the second order, the Hessian is non degenerate) by blowing up the singularities at those points. This is a generic condition on $f$, so for most $f$ all the level sets will be immersed manifolds. That said, there must be someone more qualified for a complete answer on MO.

Comment: @PierrePC anyway thank you for your comment. Now I have somewhere to start.

Comment: @PierrePC: the level sets in that case are not immersed manifolds, in general.  Locally yes it's true, but there is a global problem.  Take for example the standard linear height function on a torus.  You need to leave the smooth category and be okay with topological immersions to make sense of your answer.  I don't think there will be a non-tautological answer that is satisfactory to the OP.  The main reason is that immersed submanifolds aren't level sets of any natural family of functions on manifolds that I know of.

Comment: @RyanBudney I am not sure I understand your example. Are you thinking of the height function for a donut balancing on its tip (or say a tire in its normal use position)? In this situation I don't see the problem, since the singular cases are points or figure eights.

Comment: @PierrePC: Apologies, I grabbed too simple an example.  Take for example, $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$.  This is a purely local problem.

Comment: @RyanBudney Ah yes, I see. You're saying the pinching of a cylinder into a cone is not an immersion; I had a wrong picture in mind indeed.

Comment: @RyanBudney so if every critical point is Morse, level sets are locally smooth immersed submanifolds and globally topological immersed manifolds? Or level sets are globally topological immersed manifolds no matter what condition you put to critical points?

Comment: For a Morse function the level sets are not immersed manifolds, in general.  There is an onto map to the level sets, but its derivative has rank $1$ on a large subspace.  So in the special case your ambient manifold has dimension $2$, this isn't a problem (as Pierre PC observed) but when your ambient manifold is $3$ dimensional (or higher dimensional) this is a real problem, in the smooth setting.   If you are okay living in the topological world, yes you can resolve the problem for certain types of critical points, but not all.

Comment: @RyanBudney thank you.

Comment: @PierrePC thank you too.